# ion-textarea autoGrow="true" on modal, work only the first time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a strange behaviour with ion-textarea autoGrow="true" that was introduced in ionic 4.4, the first time the autoGrow is made correctly. The 2nd time the textarea is less than 1 row. We can't event see the text.

First time :

[image: First time the modal is opened]

2nd time :
[image: 2nd time...]

I open the modal like this

```
 displayModal(data) {
this.modalCtrl.create({
  component: EventDetailModalComponent, componentProps: {
    event: data.appointmentData,
    timeFormat: this.timeFormat,
    dateFormat: this.dateFormat
  }
}).then(modalElement => {
  modalElement.present();
});  }
```

And close like this :

```
   onCancel() { this.modalCtrl.dismiss(); }
```

View contains :

```
 <ion-item lines="none">
        <ion-label position="floating">{{'DESCRIPTION' | translate }}</ion-label>
        <ion-textarea readonly disabled autoGrow="true" class="ion-text-justify" value="{{ description }}" ></ion-textarea>
 </ion-item>
```

For info, the text is inserted manually by the programme in value="x", not entered by the user.

I'm running the last version of ionic ("@ionic-native/core": "^5.11.0") and Angular (8.2).

Same problem tested on last version of Chrome, Safari and FireFox on Mac.

Comment: Hello, Please see : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-ion-textarea-autogrowth
The first time you click : "TEST MODAL HERE", you will have a correct "lorem ipsum", then close, then re-open, you will then almost not see the text correctly.

Comment: interesting. Seems to work fine if it's not a modal, yes. Looks to me a bit like a bug. maybe report it as a bug with ionic?

Comment: For info this was reported to ionic team : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18993

Answer (score 1):

nd::deep is deprecated

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Adding this in global.scss worked for me

```
ion-textarea {
    min-height: 40px;
    textarea {
        min-height: 40px;
    }
}
```

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can set a min-height on the textarea child element of ion-textarea like so

```css
::ng-deep textarea {
    min-height: 45px;
}
```